# elasticsearch sort nested_filter not matching nested_path

Tags: sorting, elasticsearch, filter, nested

I have an index with items of this form

```
{
        "_index": "identity-index",
        "_source": {
           "names": [
              "test"
           ],
           "private": {
              "lists": [
                 {
                    "listId": "56b8a0197f3c56654f8751b5",
                    "ratings": [
                       {
                          "rating": 4,
                          "authorId": "56499b7a97e3aa857cdc4f1d"
                       },
                       {
                          "rating": 4,
                          "authorId": "56b36646a24d50866de77928"
                       },
                       {
                          "rating": 4,
                          "authorId": "56cb16005082871b33ab1a60"
                       },
                       {
                          "rating": 4,
                          "authorId": "56b216a4c28edca956fe96d4"
                       },
                       {
                          "rating": 4,
                          "authorId": "56b34e8d8e324180259252f7"
                       }
                    ]
                 },
                 {
                    "listId": "56c1c508da49cdd9662b102c"
                 }
              ]
           }
        },
        "sort": [
           "-Infinity"
        ]
     }
```

I want to sort them by average rating given a listId:

I've tried a lot of ways and the closest I got was with this:

```
"sort": {
                    "private.lists.ratings.rating": {
                          "missing": "_last",
                          "order": "desc",
                          "mode": "avg",
                          "nested_path": "private.lists.ratings",
                          "nested_filter": {
                            "term": {
                              "private.lists.listId": "56c1c508da49cdd9662b102c"
                            }
                          }
                    }
              },
```

The problem is that this scores everything as -Inf. I can't find any way to sort the nested elements in private.lists.ratings but taking into account the filter by private.lists.listId. The nested_path and nested_filter fields are different and I don't think they are supposed to be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the `ratings` field is analyzed with type `nested`, you can get what you want by copying the `listId` in each of the nested objects.

Unfortunately, nested objects are not part of the main document, and `nested_filter` (and `nested_sort`) can only disambiguate based on properties contained in each subdocument.

One solution could be to flatten your structure to a simple list of objects looking like the following

```
{
  "listId": "56b8a0197f3c56654f8751b5",
  "rating": 4,
  "authorId": "56499b7a97e3aa857cdc4f1d"
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I was afraid of that. Unfortunately flattening isn't a solution. I'm giving scripts a go, but I can't seem to manage to write a correct groovy script.